# Django user validation fail just gives 500 Server Error

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

Let's saying I'm adding a user and I want to fail it for some arbitrary reason.

in `signals.py`,

```
def user_presave_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    raise ValidationError('You are a bad person')
pre_save.connect(user_presave_handler, User)
```

The webpage that the user sees is

(500) Internal Server Error

How do I make that instead notify the user of what went wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You should use form or field validation for this. Signals are not good use case for that.

Comment: @Rohan that would be nice, but there's some complex DB stuff that happens behind the scenes in some of the signals that help determine if they're valid or not

Comment: @Rohan as a simple example, making sure the username is unique. I know that Django handles this on its own, but let's pretend that it doesn't, since in my use case there are certain usernames that are equivalent that Django doesn't see that way

Comment: You can create custom validation rules for model fields, so you could let Django handle the conflicting username issue. The signal doesn't have access to the HTTP request, so there's no way for it to return a message to the page. Use validators. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/validators/.

Comment: How to use a validator on the already-existing User model? Also, although the signal does not have access to the HTTP request, I was hoping that the exception could be propagated back to the form that is doing the posting in some magic easy Django way, by specifying a template for failure on that screen or something. Looks like I'll have to modify the template to use JS to make the post and check the return body, or something like that.